# Can't mount NTFS partition with write permissions

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, fstab, ntfs-3g

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 and during setup I added my data drive which is ntfs, to automount in /etc/fstab file. The entry looks like this -

```
UUID=EA469A60469A2D77   /alpha  ntfs-3g rw,permissions,umask=0022,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,locale=en_US.UTF-8  0       0
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to get write access to the mounted NTFS partition.

EDIT1:

> ```
> prenx@prenx4x:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
> NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
> sdb           111.8G            
> ├─sdb2 swap    18.6G [SWAP]     
> └─sdb1 ext4    93.2G /          
> sdc             3.7T            
> ├─sdc2 ntfs     3.7T /zeta      Zeta
> └─sdc1          128M            
> sda           953.9G            
> ├─sda4 ntfs   952.9G /alpha     ALPHA
> ├─sda2 vfat      99M            
> ├─sda5 ntfs     450M            
> ├─sda3          128M            
> └─sda1 ntfs     300M            Recovery
> ```

After changing any option I test it using mkdir-

```
prenx@prenx4x:/alpha$ mkdir a
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a’: Read-only file system
prenx@prenx4x:/alpha$ sudo mkdir a
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a’: Read-only file system
```

Also I am unable to paste or create anything in any sub-folder as well.

Comment: Is your "data drive" actually the C: drive in Windows, or some other drive letter?

Comment: the /alpha shown above is C drive, the /zeta is just a data drive with no OS in it. Both are mounted as read only.

Comment: see my answer, below...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this:

## in Windows

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: you can stop at the point *close the Power control panel*, below points quite complicated and may not need for some cases. it worked with for me with Ubuntu 16.10 and Windows 10

Comment: @vanduc1102 No, you need to follow the **complete** instructions that I've given.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! BTW I did need to run chkdsk on both drives; I checked, out of curiosity.

Comment: Nope, not on mine. Mounts fine under windows. Mounts and writes fine under one linux system. Just not the other one!

Comment: @Owl please start a new question to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, for me @vanduc1102 was right, it was all that was needed, NTFS partition now mounts as writable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rw`, `permissions`, `umask=0022`, `user`, `exec`, `uid=1000`, and `gid=1000` seems excessive.

The [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) is pretty straight forward.

Something like this should work for your purposes:

`UUID=EA469A60469A2D77   /alpha  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0`

Comment: I tried these options but they are also not working for me.

Comment: What happens exactly?  Can you explain in a little further detail?  Also, can you post the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` in your question?

Comment: Also about using all these many options, I reached here one option at a time, but none of those worked for me.

Comment: I know this may be a silly question, but have you done `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`?

Comment: Yes. I looked at some other forums, and they suggested sudo apt-get purge ntfsprogs, sudo apt-get purge ntfs-3g, sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g which I did. Plus the partitions are getting mounted as read only.

Comment: What about using `/dev/sda4` instead of `UUID=EA469A60469A2D77`?

Comment: when I changed to /dev/sd4 from UUID, ubuntu didn't like that and it hanged and refused to boot.