# Ubuntu 17.10 Mounts Windows Partition As Read Only

Tags: mount, windows, nautilus

Ubuntu 17.10 is mounting the Windows partition as read only when I use Nautilus. Shame for me, because I have to edit documents saved on the C drive. Is there anyway for Nautilus to not do that?

Mounting from the command line still works, by the way. Just Nautilus insists on mounting it as read only.

Comment: Did you disable Windows fast startup?
As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857089/cant-mount-ntfs-partition-with-write-permissions).

Comment: @StefanFabian Yes, I did disable fast startup. It seems to be more of a Nautilus thing than anything else, since mounting the partition by command line still works.

Comment: @ZhehaoChen I think you should **[edit]** the question and add the important info that mounting from command-line works fine.